# require('./file') is undefined in one file, but not others

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have an npm project I am working on and am having a strange issue with `require`. I have paths in one file and am using them like, `const paths = require('./paths');` but I have one file where paths ends up as `undefined`.

Project Directory

```
my-project
- main.js
- a.js
- b.js
- paths.js
```

main.js

```
const a = require('./a');
const b = require('./b');
const paths = require('./paths');

async function mainFunction() {
    console.log(paths); // no problem

    await a.process();
    await b.process();
}

mainFunction();
```

a.js

```
const paths = require('./paths');

async function process() {
    console.log(paths); // no problem
}

module.exports.process = process;
```

b.js - doesn't work

```
const paths = require('./paths');

async function process() {
    console.log(paths); // undefined
}

module.exports.process = process;
```

b.js - does work

```
async function process() {
    const paths = require('./paths');
    console.log(paths); // no problem
}

module.exports.process = process;
```

paths.js

```
thePaths = {
    pathOne: '/the-path',
    // etc.
};

module.exports = {thePaths};
```

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem, but my first suggestion would be to quadruple check that you typed "paths" correctly in the code you're running.

Comment: @twiz I copied and pasted it out of a working file, but that is a great suggestion. Wouldn't be the first time I was baffled by a typo.

Comment: Plus it would through a `paths not defined error` instead of an undefined value, which I did try

Comment: Is this a typo `pathOne: /the-path,` in `paths.js`? After fixing this line, the code works as expected with Node.js version 16.14.2: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-pstmm8?file=paths.js I can't reproduce the problem. The code is correct. The problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: @jabaa you are correct that I have a typo in what I listed here, but you failed to recognize that when I move the `require` into the function it works correctly. You also have not explained why it works in the other files. I have updated the code above.

Comment: I posted an example project in my previous comment. It's a working example of your code. Try to reproduce the problem in Stackblitz and add a link. Currently, your problem isn't reproducible. The code is correct. I've copied your code, so that even hidden characters or typos would be copied.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to your question. Write an answer for it or delete the question, because it's not reproducible.

Answer (score -2):

I created a new file with a different name and copied the contents into it. Turns out I had another file with `const b = require(./b);` that wasn't using it and it was causing the problem. Definitely an odd-ball.

c.js

```
const b = require('./b'); // removed to resolve issue
// other requires

// file contents
```

Comment: I don't understand the answer. How does a copy with a different name solve the problem and what was the cause for the problem? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @jabaa I don't have an explanation. All I can say is that there was another file that was requiring `b.js` and when I removed it from that file the problem went away.

Comment: IMO, this answer is not really useful, without any clarification or explanation. `const b = require('./b');` in `main.js` doesn't cause this problem but `const b = require('./b');` in some `c.js`, that isn't imported or evaluated and that's not even in the project directory, causes an error. That makes no sense and is not reproducible.